# Как отображать определенные данные в <select> в зависимости от значений в другом <select>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! У меня на страницу есть два `<select>`. В каждом из них располагаются даты в формате `dd.mm.yyyy`.

```html
<select id="s1">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Дата1</option>
        <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
        <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
        <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
        <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
        <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Дата2</option>
        <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
        <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
        <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
        <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
        <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>
```

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы при выборе даты в `s1`, в `s2` отображались только те даты, которые "старше", чем выбранная дата в `s1`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#s1").change(function(){
  var date = $(this).find("option:selected").data("date");
  $("#s2 option").each(function(){
    if (!$(this).data("date"))
      return;
    if ($(this).data("date") > date) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      if ($(this).prop("selected")) 
        $("#s2 option").eq(0).prop("selected", true); 
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Дата1</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180127">27.01.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180217">17.02.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180324">24.03.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180431">31.04.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180506">06.05.2018</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Дата2</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180127">27.01.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180217">17.02.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180324">24.03.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180431">31.04.2018</option>
        <option value="" data-date="20180506">06.05.2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант №1**, не боится динамического контента (если количество или содержимое option'ов изменяется после загрузки страницы):

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById('s1'), 
    s2 = document.getElementById('s2'); 
s1.addEventListener('change', filterS2Options); 

function filterS2Options() {
  s2.selectedIndex = 0;
  let s1Date = dateStrToNum(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text); 
  for (let opt of s2.options)
    opt.style.display = (s1Date < dateStrToNum(opt.text)) ? null : 'none'; 
}

function dateStrToNum(dateStr) {
  let dc = dateStr.split('.'); 
  return (dc.length !== 3) ? 0 : +(dc[2].padStart(4, '0') + dc[1].padStart(2, '0') + dc[0].padStart(2, '0')); 
}
```

```html
<select id="s1">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Дата1</option>
  <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
  <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
  <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
  <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
  <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Дата2</option>
  <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
  <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
  <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
  <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
  <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>
```

**Вариант №2**, с заполнением data-атрибутов (подойдет если option'ы не изменяются после загрузки страницы):

```js
var s2;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let s1 = document.getElementById('s1'); 
  s2 = document.getElementById('s2'); 
  fillOptionsDataset(s1); 
  fillOptionsDataset(s2); 
  s1.addEventListener('change', filterS2Options); 
});

function filterS2Options() {
  s2.selectedIndex = 0;
  let s1Date = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset.date; 
  for (let opt of s2.options)
    opt.style.display = (+s1Date < +opt.dataset.date) ? null : 'none'; 
}

function fillOptionsDataset(selectEl) {
  let dc, i; 
  for (opt of selectEl.options) {
    dc = opt.text.split('.'); 
    opt.dataset.date = (dc.length !== 3) ? 0 :
      dc[2].padStart(4, '0') + dc[1].padStart(2, '0') + dc[0].padStart(2, '0'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="s1">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Дата1</option>
  <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
  <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
  <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
  <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
  <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Дата2</option>
  <option value="">27.01.2018</option>
  <option value="">17.02.2018</option>
  <option value="">24.03.2018</option>
  <option value="">31.04.2018</option>
  <option value="">06.05.2018</option>
</select>
```

---

Оба варианта не требуют правок HTML-разметки или использования каких-либо библиотек.
Поддерживают формат дат `[d]d.[m]m.[[[y]y]y]y`, проверки на валидность *нет*.
Если захотите поменять символ разделителя, с точки на что-то другое - измените значение аргумента `split`.